# ExtJS floating panel appeared in a wrong place because other components above it takes time to display

Tags: javascript, extjs, position, floating

I display Panel A first, then display Panel B below it. Panel A uses JSONP to get the data and is shown in the callback function of the store load. So it takes about 1 sec to show.

I aligned a floating panel C to Panel B. The floating panel C is something like this:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.MyWindow', {
    extend: 'Ext.window.Window',

    height: 334,
    width: 540,
    layout: {
        type: 'border'
    },
    title: 'Run report',

    initComponent: function () {
        var me = this;
        floatingpanel = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
            html: "something",
            width: 100,
            height: 50,
            floating: true,
            listeners: {
                'show': {
                    fn: function () {
                        floatingpanel.alignTo(PanelB, "tr-tr", [left, top]);
                    },
                    scope: floatingpanel,
                    //delay: 1000, // to wait for other component to show
                    single: true
                }
            }
        });


        Ext.applyIf(me, {
            items: [{
                xtype: 'form',
                bodyPadding: 10,
                region: 'center'
            }]
        });

        me.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

Then `floatingpanel.show()` is called to display the panel. It is not added to Panel B though.

If I don't use `delay` as shown above, the floating panel C appeared somewhere in Panel A since Panel A is not available yet when the floating panel is about to show. So I put the "delay".

After 1 sec, Panel A is shown as the callback succeeded. Now the floating panel C aligns to Panel B in the right place.

Since the callback function may succeed in 1 sec or 10 sec, the delay time is hard to choose.

Are there other ways to work this out? I tried to use doConstrain to attach the floating panel C to Panel B: `floatingpanel.doConstrain(PanelB)`. But somehow it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
initComponent: function () {
    var me = this;
    floatingpanel = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
        html: "something",
        width: 100,
        height: 50,
       // floating: true,
        listeners: {
            'show': {
                fn: function () {
                    me.alignTo(PanelB, "tr-tr", [left, top]);
                },
                scope: floatingpanel,
                //delay: 1000, // to wait for other component to show
                single: true
            }
        }
    });


    Ext.applyIf(me, {
        items: [{
            xtype: 'form',
            bodyPadding: 10,
            region: 'center'
        }]
    });

    me.callParent(arguments);
}
```

> please use above code instead of ..